# css background-image basic fail

Tags: html, css

The following code is a test and it attempts to repeat a 2.8mb .png file. The file sample.png is in the same folder as index.html.

I dont know why, but it does not show the background picture.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello</title>
<style type="text/css">
body { background-image: url(“sample.png”); }
</style>
</head>
<body>
Hello
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `“”` into `""`. That maybe not supported in html document. If you view it in the browser, there is no image. But when you right-clicked the page and click view source, your css scripts might look like this. `body { background-image: url(â€œsample.pngâ€); }`

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes not double quotes. `background-image: url('sample.png');`

Comment: You can use double quotes just not special character double quotes.
`“` vs `"`

Comment: @Press correct http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#uri but the single quote was the fastest way to fix his issue and it looks good in any editor.